# How can I insert an image in a MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I am using this form:

```
<FORM action="testimage1.php" method="post">
                 <div style="font:bold 10px arial,serif;" >Product Name*</div>
                 <input type="text" name="myuserName" maxlength="50" /><br />
                  <div style="font:bold 10px arial,serif;" >Upload a photo</div>
                 <input name="uploadimage" type="file" /></br>
                 <div style="font:bold 10px arial,serif;">Product Description:</div> <input type="text" name="product" value=""></br>
                 <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /><br />
                 </form>
```

and in test1.php

```
require_once("dbconnect.inc.php");  //for database connection                   
    $db_name="thinstrokes";                                     
     $tbl_name="product";
     $db_selected=mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    // Connect to server and select databse.
    // username and password sent from form 
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
    $myproduct=$_POST['product'];
    $filename=$_POST['uploadimage'];

$imgData = file_get_contents($filename);
    $size = getimagesize($filename);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product
    (productname, image_id , image_type ,image, image_size, image_name,productdesc)
    VALUES
    ('$myusername','11', '{$size['mime']}', '{$imgData}', '{$size[3]}', 
     '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}','$productdesc')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("error in uploading/*");
```

and getting errors are:-

*file_get_contents(DSC02945.JPG) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\thinstrokes original site\testimage1.php on line 22*

Warning: getimagesize(DSC02945.JPG) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\thinstrokes original site\testimage1.php on line 23

how can i correct it..???

Comment: enctype should be multipart/form-data

Comment: also check if `image` attribute in `product` table is `BLOB` type (otherwise the binary data can be messed up due to charset conversion)

Comment: why are you want to insert the image in database ....generally we store the images in a folder and store the image name in db...it will make your db clean......

Comment: i am only want to add a image jpg/png not the folder

Comment: You need to `$imgData` (and ***everything else***) through `mysql_real_escape_string` before putting it in a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need enctype=multipart/form-data in your form declaration. And access the file through the $_FILES variable instead of the $_POST variable. Like:

```
<form action="testimage1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="uploadimage" type="file" />
</form>

<?php
    $filename = $_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'];   
?>
```

Comment: That's a whole other problem. You file upload now succeeded, which is an answer to the current question.

Answer (score -1):

```
$imgData = file_get_contents($filename);
$size = getimagesize($filename);
mysql_connect("localhost", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db ("$dbname");
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO testblob
    (image_type, image, image_size, image_name)
    VALUES
    ('%s', '%s', '%d', '%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($size['mime']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($imgData),
    $size[3],
    mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['userfile']['name'])
    );
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Please explain what it was that you corrected, and what the mistake was.