# To upload a image in MySql database via php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am currently working on a website that needs to upload the images of different products by its users. I am implementing it by using MySql database via php.

My code for a basic form for taking input from users is:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testimage1.php" method="post" name="changer">
<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">
<input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
<input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

My database table is:

```
 mysql> CREATE TABLE tbl_images (
 > id tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 > image blob NOT NULL,
 > PRIMARY KEY (id)
 > );
```

testimage1.php has the following code:-

```
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $host = "localhost";
 $database = "thinstrokes";


 $link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
 if (!$link) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

// Select your database
mysql_select_db ($database);

    if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

  // Temporary file name stored on the server
  $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

  // Read the file 
  $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
  $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
  $data = addslashes($data);
  fclose($fp);


  // Create the query and insert
  // into our database.
  $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images ";
  $query .= "(image) VALUES ('$data')";
  $results = mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error());

  // Print results
  print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

  }
  else {
  print "No image selected/uploaded";
  }
```

On submitting the form I am getting an error: `No image selected/uploaded`

I am not getting the error... and I've already asked for this before as:

- [mysql error during inserting a image in mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829775/mysql-error-during-inserting-a-image-in-mysql-database)
- [How can I insert an image in a MySQL database using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829313/how-can-i-insert-an-image-in-a-mysql-database-using-php)

But until now I am not successful in storing the image in the database.

Comment: "on submitting the form I am getting error" -- "I am not getting the error" -- so, are you seeing an error when you submit the form or not? If you *are* seeing the "No image selected/uploaded" error, I would recommending var_dump($_FILES) to see if it contains the data you are expecting it to contain.

Comment: What's the purpose of using fopen??

Comment: You script is working properly, check my answer

Comment: it is not working in my laptop,and i am using xampp-win32-1.7.3..and using mysql of xampp

Comment: @greggory.hz sry i am getting the error and that error is.."No image selected/uploaded"..

Comment: As Ahoura points out, the script *looks* fine. There is almost certainly something else causing problems. Since you're getting the "No image selected/uploaded" error, "isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0" is returning false. Start there. See what data is actually in $_FILES and work from that.

Comment: @greggory.hz..thanks for your reply..ya i got that..it is working fine for small size images and for bigger images error is(if i want to upload a image name DSCN1005.JPG of size 733kb ) :-    array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "DSCN1005.JPG" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(2) ["size"]=> int(0) } } No image selected/uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is working just fine, This is what I test:

```
<?

if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

  // Temporary file name stored on the server
  $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

  // Read the file 
  $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
  $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
  $data = addslashes($data);
  fclose($fp);


  // Create the query and insert

  // Print results
  print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

  }
  else {
  print "No image selected/uploaded";
  }

?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" name="changer">
<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">
<input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
<input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

And it works just fine, if you want to see it in action I can send you the link.

It must be something else that is ruining your code (*note that I removed the DB queries to avoid getting mysql errors but the script was working even with them there.

Comment: ya i get it...it is only working for images less than 20kb..and i want to upload image of bigger size..?

Comment: do you want me to send a new piece of code that can handle uploading the files etc??

Answer (score 0):

//Here is the solution for your problem

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" name="changer">
    <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden">
    <input name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
    <input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
<?php

    // connection to database
    include 'includes/connection.php';
?>

<?php

    if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 
        // Temporary file name stored on the server
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  
        // Read the file 
        $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $data = addslashes($data);
        fclose($fp);
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO image (image)VALUES ( '$data')", $connection);
        if(!$result)
        {
            die("Database query failed: ". mysql_error());
        }
        // Print results

        print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";
    }
    else 
    {
        print "No image selected/uploaded";
    }
?>

<?php
    //close connection
    include 'includes/close.php';
?>
```